# Select rows if it contains only one value

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, having-clause

I am trying to find all the rows that have null in Col J to Col L

My output should look like below (Green is what I expect and others should be ignored):

[image]
I tried below code but it didn't work:

```
-- Step 1 get all the data as required

select Col A,   Col B,  Col C,  Col D,  Col E,  Col F,  Col G,  Col H,  Col I,  Col J,  Col K,  Col L,
into tempDB
from MainDB

-- Step 2
select ColB, min(Col C) , min(Col D), min(Col E), min(Col F)
from tempDB 
where Col J = Col K and Col L = null
group by Col B
```

Comment: You cannot write  `Col L =  Null` in MSSQL. Try with `Col L is Null`

Comment: Your first and some other row also has NULL in Col J to Col L. Why you need to ignore them where as similar last 3 row you are considering.

Comment: 1) You can't check for `NULL` by `=`. 2) There is no `4444F...` in the sample you provide as image which is bad. Always post it as formatted text. 3) You can't have a space in the identifiers name, unless you escape it by `[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I my understanding of your requirement is correct, you want rows where all values in `ColJ`, `ColK`, `ColL` are NULL value

```
select  ColB, min(ColC) , min(ColD), min(ColE), min(ColF)
from    tempDB 
group by ColB
having  min(ColJ)   is null
and     min(ColK)   is null
and     min(ColL)   is null
```

Comment: I am getting error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'having'.`

Comment: @Duffer . . . I don't know if the answer has changed, but the syntax looks correct tome.

Comment: @Duffer, please show the query that you have tried. That query is fine without any syntax issue

Comment: @Squirrel. Thanks it worked. I have also marked your answer correct.

Answer (score 2):

Try this-

```
SELECT ColB, 
MIN(ColC) , MIN(ColD), MIN(ColE), MIN(ColF)
FROM tempDB 
GROUP BY Col B
HEVING SUM(COALESCE (ColJ,0)) = 0
AND SUM(COALESCE (ColK,0)) = 0
AND SUM(COALESCE (ColL,0)) = 0
```

Comment: @Duffer . . . Squirrel's answer is better.  This will return rows where the columns have `0` values and it could fail if the columns are not numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `IS NULL` instead of `= NULL`. You cannot compare if null is equal to something, just if it *is* null.

```sql
SELECT [ColB], MIN([Col C]), MIN([Col D]), MIN([Col E]), MIN([Col F]) 
FROM tempDB 
WHERE [Col J] IS NULL
  AND [Col K] IS NULL
  AND [Col L] IS NULL
GROUP BY [Col B]
```

Comment: Column names are invalid and they should be inside []

Answer (score 1):

this should work.

```
SELECT *
FROM tempdb
where colj is null and colk is null and coll is null
```

You should not use something=null condition because
null is not nothing but
null is something that is not defined.

further read
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp

edit:- if you want rows based colb values

```
SELECT *
FROM tempdb
where colj is null and colk is null and coll is null and colb=4444
```

put '' around 4444 if the datatype is not numerical(char,varchar etc).

Comment: Not it does not. It gives me all the rows where col J to Col K is null for some rows of the group col B, which is not correct. I want rows only group by Col B and get only rows where all the rows from Col J to Col L is null like the one marked in green.

Comment: Do you want the rows for which Colb is 4444?

Comment: Yes, I am looking to group by Col B. So only look for Null values for Col J to Col K after grouping by Col B.

Comment: I have edited my answer , I think you should get the rows you are expecting now.

Comment: 4444 is just sample whole table is more than million row. I can't insert the value implicitly.

Comment: If you want to group by colb , you will only get one row for each value of colb. For eg one row for colb=4444 and not the 3 green rows you have highlighted

Answer (score 0):

If you want `colb` where all the rows in `colj`, `colk` and `coll` contain nulls:

```
select ColB, min(ColJ), min(ColK), min(ColL)
from tempDB 
group by ColB
having coalesce(min(ColJ), min(ColK), min(ColL)) is null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  t.[Col A], 
  t.[Col B], 
  t.[Col C], 
  t.[Col D], 
  t.[Col E],
  t.[Col F],
  t.[Col G],
  t.[Col H],
  t.[Col J],
  t.[Col K],
  t.[Col L]
FROM tempDB t
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT MIN([Col B]) AS [Col B]
    FROM tempDB
    GROUP BY 
        [Col B]
    HAVING
        MIN([Col J]) IS NULL
        AND MIN([Col K]) IS NULL
        AND MIN([Col L]) IS NULL
) d
  on t.[Col B] = d.[Col B]
```